# Maven Dependencies Why is org.woden.apachi:woden-api:1.0M8 pulling down ant.jar?

Tags: maven, ivy, pom.xml

To clarify: I am using Ivy and not Maven, but I use the Maven repository structure.

I have a jar that depends upon org.apache.axis2:axis-kernel:1.5. According to the Ivy Dependecy Report I generate, axis2:axis-kernel:1.5  has a dependency on woden-api:org.apache.woden which has a dependency on org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.

I am not a developer, but I would assume that `ant.jar` (and `ant-launcher.jar`) should not be a dependency for another jar. Even stranger, I went to [Maven Org's Search](http://search.maven.org) and pulled down the [pom.xml](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/woden/woden-api/1.0M8/woden-api-1.0M8.pom) for the Woden-API, and I don't even see a dependency section in the `pom.xml`.

So, where is this dependency on ant.jar coming from? Why is my dependency report claiming that woden-api is responsible if I don't see it in the woden-api jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take closer look at `pom.xml` of `woden-api`, you'll see that it has got parent named `woden`. I guess most of the dependencies that are needed for different parts of this project are specified in [parent](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/woden/woden/1.0M8/woden-1.0M8.pom).

And here is the extract from it:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
  <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure if it's right or wrong to depend on `ant` but I know that many other artifacts depend on it.

Comment: I downloaded the source. There's no dependency for ant.jar in the `woden-api` source. In fact, the only dependency in the whole project are a few files in another sub-project, woden-ant, that builds Ant tasks. That makes sense. The problem is the master pom contains all dependencies for all sub-projects even though those sub-projects don't need them. This has been cleaned up in version 1.0M9, and I'll put that as a reference in my ivy.xml file and see if that prevents these other unneeded jars from loading.